# Metadata in openflow rule

Tags: openflow, openvswitch

This Question is extension of the following

[OpenFlow Rule Metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53771023/openflow-rule-metadata)

I would like to have this clarified, on my question about Metadata
Let us say, I have an Open Flow rules, as below

```
Cookie=0x8000001, duration=228925.445s, table=17, n_packets=350, n_bytes=32424, priority=10,metadata=0xc000f30000000000/0xffffff0000000000 actions=goto_table:19
```

I wanted to understand the following

Do we have certain rule/ Algorithm , to determine these Metadata from a Packet.

because the Packet in OVS is actually switched based on Matching Metadata, Is that correct ??  ( At least according to the above flow rule )

- And the Packet itself does not carry the Metadata, then how exactly
  the packet hitting a flow matched against the Metadata.

  So, If I understood it correctly the Packets those are traversed between the flow-tables, are within the OVS application itself or Handled @OVS Application level, until it had determined Egress Port 
  So in that Case, the MetaData are handled @OVS-Application level, until the Packets is send via Egress Port.

Is this correct??

Finally which Module in ODL is responsible for determine the Metadata, and I would like to understand from the code how exactly it was done.

Answer (score 0):

The OpenFlow metadata field [starts with a value of zero](https://github.com/openvswitch/ovs/blob/5bb6f38b90640a97ab0eb7e4347546ba25746428/include/openvswitch/meta-flow.h#L659-L660) for every packets. Tables can then writes to this field and you can match on it in subsequent tables. It is only used to carry information from one table to the next, as explained in the OpenFlow specifications:

> Metadata: a maskable register that is used to carry information from one table to the next.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you can try Ryu instead, its code is more easy to read and understand.
Then, I think metadata/instructions/actions.... these things are belong to the processing of OVS forwarding, but these things needs to attach to something and that is the packet that OVS received. About the question "Do we have certain rule/ Algorithm , to determine these Metadata from a Packet. "   I think the value of the Metadata is determind by the controller, which means that it depends on 'how do you design your own network instance using some(e.g. RYU) controller application'.